# JavaScript: Get Date of 3rd Friday of the Month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm given a date that is the 3rd Friday of the current month (5/16/2014). Based on this date, I need to find the date of the 3rd Friday of the following month (6/20/2014).

The 3rd Friday of every month is also the Friday on or following the 15th.

Comment: which part of the code are you stuck with specifically? Please show what you have so far

Comment: maybe you can do an array with days. then you know that friday is in position 4 if array begins from 0 or it is in position 5 if array begins from 1. then you cycle them and use a flag. the first time that the index of the cycle is 1 flag is assigned to 1 and ecc. when flag is 3 you have your friday

Comment: This is not my homework. This is for my company. The 3rd Friday of every month is payout day. I have no doubt I can figure this out. I just wanted some suggestions. @Irdrah

Comment: What kind of suggestions @burkybang? We don't even know what you're applying this to, what language you're writing in - or anything other than you need to calculate 3rd Fridays of every month.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I told you I'm using JavaScript. What else do you want to know?

Comment: I like the suggestion made by @Daniele94. Thank you.

Comment: We want to know what you have tried and where it went wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @burkybang: thx but it is not easy at all

Comment: @Daniele94 Ya. That's pretty much why I was asking. I wanted an easy way.

Comment: Almost everyone is here is extremely rude. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function GetNextMonthsThirdFriday(input){
    var parts = input.split('/');

    var date = new Date(parts[2], parts[0], 1);

    var fridayCount = 0;

    while (fridayCount < 3){
        if (date.getDay() === 5){
            break;
        }

        date = new Date(date.getYear() + 1900, date.getMonth(), (date.getDate() + 1));
    }

    return new Date(date.getYear() + 1900, date.getMonth(), (date.getDate() + 14));
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow, please edit your answer to include a plain English explanation of how/why your answer works.

Answer (score 1):

```
function thirdFriday(monthCount)
{
    str= "";
    mCount=0;
    day = today();
    month = day.getMonth();
    years = day.getFullYears()
    while(mCount < monthCount-1)
    {
        day = new Date(0,month,years)
        while(day.getDay()!=5)
        {
            day = day+1;
        }
        day = day+21;
        str += day+"\n";
        mCount += 1;
        month += 1;
        if(month+mCount == 11)
        {
            years += 1;
            month = 0;
        }
    }
}
// EDITED : I forgot some lines to change years
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow, please edit your answer to include a plain English explanation of how/why your answer works.

Comment: while this code would be clever by using +21 rather than iterating as @irdrah's code , to get get the 3rd Friday once you found the first, you'd need to only add 14.  Now, there are a lot of other errors: `today()` is not a function, `getFullYears()` is also not a function, and `new Date()` takes, year, month, day, not the other way around, and looks like the logic to increase `years` is also wrong